# Scripting runetime version is missing in unity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Here's a screenshot of my configuration:

[image]

and this is another person's configuration:

[image]

Where can i find it ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you just looking for [`Environment.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.version?view=net-6.0) or maybe [`Mono.Runtime.GetDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mono.runtime.getdisplayname)?

Comment: Well are you using the same version of unity as they are?

Comment: @BugFinder i have unity 2021.3.7f1 and the other one is 2018.3.5f1

Comment: Well they did drop support I think for some options between then so it’s not too surprising you have different options. If you wish to work on the same project you need to do the same versions

Answer (score 0):

The .NET version used by the Unity project.

1. In the Unity editor, click the menu Edit -> Project Setting -> Player.
2. Find Scripting Runtime Version* and select the corresponding .NET version.

[image]